# Will it be fine to charge my iPad with 61W MBP charger

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ipad, mac, charging

I have a MBP charger which is 61w. I normally use it for charging my MBP. Can I use it to charge my iPad 5th Generation? Will it cause any damage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe and shouldn't cause any damage. The iPad actually determines the power it receives.

For more information look at [this](https://9to5mac.com/2018/08/17/use-macbook-pro-charger-with-iphone-ipad/) article